# Empty response in CPI iFlow

Tags: odata, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cpi

I'm at the beginning of the development of an iFlow in SAP CPI. I tested the credentials and the OData query via Postman and got the expected result.

However, when doing the same steps via SCPI iFlow, the result of the request reply is blank.

Here are the Postman details with the result:

> [image]

And the SCPI settings:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

The empty result:

> [image]

What am I forgetting or not doing right?

Thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting Request Header as * and see if that works.